# Tensorflow: How to ignore specific labels during semantic segmentation?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow for semantic segmentation. How can I tell tensorflow to ignore a specific label when computing the pixelwise loss?

I've read [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091432/tensorflow-softmax-ignore-negative-labels-just-like-caffe/39113607) that for image classification one can set the label to `-1` and it will be ignored. If that is true, given the label-tensor, how can I modify my labels such that certain values are changed to `-1`?

In Matlab it would be something like:

```
ignore_label = 255
myLabelTensor(myLabelTensor == ignore_label) = -1
```

But I don't know how to do this in TF?

Some background info:
This is how the labels are loaded:

```
label_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[1])
label = tf.image.decode_png(label_contents, channels=1)
```

This is how the loss is currently computed:

```
raw_output = net.layers['fc1_voc12']
prediction = tf.reshape(raw_output, [-1, n_classes])
label_proc = prepare_label(label_batch, tf.pack(raw_output.get_shape()[1:3]),n_classes)
gt = tf.reshape(label_proc, [-1, n_classes])

# Pixel-wise softmax loss.
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, gt)
reduced_loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)
```

with

```
def prepare_label(input_batch, new_size, n_classes):
    """Resize masks and perform one-hot encoding.

    Args:
      input_batch: input tensor of shape [batch_size H W 1].
      new_size: a tensor with new height and width.

    Returns:
      Outputs a tensor of shape [batch_size h w 21]
      with last dimension comprised of 0's and 1's only.
    """
    with tf.name_scope('label_encode'):
        input_batch = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(input_batch, new_size) # as labels are integer numbers, need to use NN interp.
        input_batch = tf.squeeze(input_batch, squeeze_dims=[3]) # reducing the channel dimension.
        input_batch = tf.one_hot(input_batch, depth=n_classes)
    return input_batch
```

I'm using the [tensorflow-deeplab-resnet model](https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet) which transfers the Resnet model implemented in Caffe to tensorflow using [caffe-tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow: How to handle void labeled data in image segmentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097968/tensorflow-how-to-handle-void-labeled-data-in-image-segmentation)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) must be called with valid probability distributions on `labels`, or otherwise the computation will be incorrect, and using [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/classification#sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) (which might be more convenient in your case) with negative labels will either cause an error or return NaN values. I wouldn't rely on it to have some labels ignored.

What I would do is to replace the logits for the ignored class with infinity in those pixels where the correct class is the ignored one, so they will contribute nothing to the loss:

```
ignore_label = ...
# Make zeros everywhere except for the ignored label
input_batch_ignored = tf.concat(input_batch.ndims - 1,
    [tf.zeros_like(input_batch[:, :, :, :ignore_label]),
     tf.expand_dims(input_batch[:, :, :, ignore_label], -1),
     tf.zeros_like(input_batch[:, :, :, ignore_label + 1:])])
# Make corresponding logits "infinity" (a big enough number)
predictions_fix = tf.select(input_batch_ignored > 0,
    1e30 * tf.ones_like(predictions), predictions)
# Compute loss with fixed logits
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, gt)
```

The only problem with this is that you are considering that pixels of the ignored class are always predicted correctly, which means that the loss for images containing a lot of those pixels will be artificially smaller. Depending on the case this may or may not be significant, but if you want to be really accurate, you would have to weight the loss of each image according to the number of not ignored pixels, instead of just taking the mean.

```
# Count relevant pixels on each image
input_batch_relevant = 1 - input_batch_ignored
input_batch_weight = tf.reduce_sum(input_batch_relevant, [1, 2, 3])
# Compute relative weights
input_batch_weight = input_batch_weight / tf.reduce_sum(input_batch_weight)
# Compute reduced loss according to weights
reduced_loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss * input_batch_weight)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't fully understand the answer: What does the output of `input_batch_ignored = tf.concat(...)` look like? It seems to have the same shape as `predict` (N x H x W x C) with `zeros` in all channels (C) except for the ignore label channel. But that would mean I predict the ignore_label class for all pixels in the images right? I guess I need to select only those pixels who have the `ignore_label` as `gt_label`, right? So I would need some operation like Matlab's `(myLabelTensor == ignore_label)` to get the indices of those labels...

Comment: @mcExchange As you said, `input_batch_ignored` is all zeros except for the ignored class, for which the ones of `input_batch` are preserved. This is multiplied by infinity and added to the logits, effectively changing the prediction so pixels of the ignored class are always correct (I'm thinking now whether infinity may give bad results and instead a sufficiently big number should be used). This means these pixels will contribute 0 to the final cost.

Comment: @mcExchange If you want to replace the ignored label with -1 you can do something like `label_wo_ignored = tf.select(label != ignore_label, label, -1 * tf.ones_like(label))`, but I'm not sure that will give you the loss you want (I mean at least not according to the docs).

Comment: Ahh `tf.select(...)` sounds like a good option. Not for replacing `ignore_label` with `-1` but to generate the variable `input_batch_ignored`. In your example above I would add `inf` values across both spatial dimensions (height and width) of the image. Instead I'd like to set the predictions to `inf` only to those pixels which correspond to `ignore_label`.

Comment: @mcExchange I've edited the answer to use a big number instead of infinity, just in case it may break computations at some point.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to write a custom loss function that ignores predictions for labels of your choosing.

I can't provide exact code for semantic segmentation but this is how I tackled the issue when working on a simple *named entity recognition* problem where I wanted to ignore predictions for specific tokens (like `[PAD]`, `[SEP]` etc.) when computing the loss during model training.

```py
tokens = ['My', 'name', 'is', 'Robert', '[PAD]']
classes = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0, 1, -1]])
predictions = tf.constant([[-0.5, -0.6, -0.9, 1.2, 0.1]])
```

This is a binary classification, so `BinaryCrossentropy` loss can be used:

```py
tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(classes, predictions)

>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.47207958>
```

However, just using TensorFlow's `BinaryCrossentropy` would not ignore predictions for elements with label `-1`. To ignore them, we can use custom loss function:

```py
def custom_loss(batch_labels, batch_predictions):

    loss = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
    binary_crossentropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
    
    batch_size = tf.shape(batch_labels)[0]
    
    for i in range(batch_size):
        labels = batch_labels[i, :]
        predictions = batch_predictions[i, :]
        
        ix_to_eval = labels != -1
        
        predictions = predictions[ix_to_eval]
        labels = labels[ix_to_eval]
        element_loss = binary_crossentropy(labels, predictions)
        loss = loss + element_loss
        
    return loss/tf.cast(batch_size, tf.float32)
```

Custom loss takes as an input predictions and labels for one batch of datapoints. Here I iterate over the batch and compute `BinaryCrossentropy` only for tokens in the sentences with label different from `-1`.

Note the difference:

```py
custom_loss(classes, predictions)

>>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=0.3790003>
```

Custom loss can be used in a training loop like any other built-in loss function, e.g.:

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizer,
    loss=custom_loss)
```

Answer (score -3):

Sorry, I'm new to this but I believe in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/faq.md, it is mentioned that new datasets need to be added here. In "segmentation_dataset.py", at each dataset, you get to specify ignore_label. For example,

```
_PASCAL_VOC_SEG_INFORMATION = DatasetDescriptor(
    splits_to_sizes={
        'train': 1464,
        'trainval': 2913,
        'val': 1449,
    },
    num_classes=21,
    ignore_label=255,
)
```