# Tensorflow softmax does not ignore masking value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am reviving this github [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27010) because I believe it is valid and needs to be explained. tf.keras has a masking layer with docs that reads

> For each timestep in the input tensor (dimension #1 in the tensor), if
> all values in the input tensor at that timestep are equal to
> mask_value, then the timestep will be masked (skipped) in all
> downstream layers (as long as they support masking).
>
> If any downstream layer does not support masking yet receives such an
> input mask, an exception will be raised.

```
# create padded zeros and change two valid entries.
inputs = np.zeros([1,5])
inputs[0,1] = 0.5
inputs[0,2] = 0.1
inputs = tf.Variable(inputs)
masked_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0.0)(inputs)
with_masking = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(masked_inputs)
without_masking = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(inputs)
```

The two results are virtually identical

```
with_masking
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.1737954 , 0.28654018, 0.19207363, 0.1737954 , 0.1737954 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
without_masking
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0.1737954 , 0.28654017, 0.19207362, 0.1737954 , 0.1737954 ]])>
```

## Expected behavior

I expected to just take softmax of the valid entries, similiar to

```
#Assign one large value 
inputs = np.zeros([1,2])
inputs[0,0] = 0.5
inputs[0,1] = 0.1
inputs = tf.Variable(inputs)
without_masking = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(inputs)

without_masking
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0.59868766, 0.40131234]])>
```

padded at the correct positions

```
with_masking
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0 , 0.59868766, 0.40131234, 0, 0 ]],
      dtype=float32)>
```

To ignore 0's in a softmax function, we could switch out massively negative numbers?

Related: [tensorflow - softmax ignore negative labels (just like caffe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091432/tensorflow-softmax-ignore-negative-labels-just-like-caffe)

```
from tensorflow import __version__
__version__
'2.3.1'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is already explained well in the [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27010) you have linked. Underlying problem is that irrespective of whether an array is masked or not, `softmax()` still operates on `0.0` values and returns a `non-zero` value as mathematically expected ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function)).

The only way to get a zero output from a `softmax()` is to pass a **very small float value**. If you set the masked values to the minimum possible machine limit for `float64`, `Softmax()` of this value will be zero.

To get machine limit on float64 you need `tf.float64.min` which is equal to `-1.7976931348623157e+308`. More info about machine limits on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65657086/how-can-i-express-this-custom-loss-function-in-tensorflow/65658222#65658222).

Here is an implementation for your reference on `tf.boolean_mask` only, and the correct method of using `tf.where` for creating the mask and passing it to `softmax()` -

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = np.zeros([1,5])
inputs[0,1] = 0.5
inputs[0,2] = 0.1
inputs = tf.Variable(inputs)

#Returns only the elements that are not masked (2,)
with_boolmask = tf.boolean_mask(inputs, inputs!=0)
with_boolmask = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(with_boolmask)

#Correct way to do it!
masked_inp = tf.where(inputs!=0, inputs, tf.float64.min) #<----
with_where = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(masked_inp)

print('BOOLEAN MASK (NOT EXPECTED)')
print(with_boolmask)

print('')
print('MASKED INPUT - ')
print(masked_inp)
print('')
print('SOFTMAX OUTPUT')
print(with_where)
```

```
BOOLEAN MASK (NOT EXPECTED)
tf.Tensor([0.59868765 0.40131232], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)

MASKED INPUT - 
tf.Tensor(
[[-1.79769313e+308  5.00000000e-001  1.00000000e-001 -1.79769313e+308
  -1.79769313e+308]], shape=(1, 5), dtype=float64)

SOFTMAX OUTPUT
tf.Tensor([[0.         0.59868765 0.40131232 0.         0.        ]], shape=(1, 5), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Clear, helpful and well answered.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I think we have an easy way to do it.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math

# create padded zeros and change two valid entries.
inputs = tf.constant([0., 0.5, 0.1, 0., 0.])
mask = tf.not_equal(inputs, 0.)
with_masking = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(inputs, mask=mask)
without_masking = tf.keras.layers.Softmax()(inputs)

print(with_masking)
print(without_masking)
```

And output is,

```sh
tf.Tensor([0.         0.59868765 0.40131232 0.         0.        ], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([0.1737954  0.28654018 0.19207363 0.1737954  0.1737954 ], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
```